# Is it possible to get the coordinates of every div on a view and save them in local storage in a javascript onunload() function?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, local-storage, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a view that contains two divs that hold images. I have implemented JQuery's draggable functionality and have both divs placed within a container. I would like to save the coordinates of the divs in local storage upon a user leaving the view and/or refreshing the view. Storing in a database would not be ideal for my current situation.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#pieChart').draggable
    ({
            containment: $("#myContainer"),
            cursor: "hand",
            opacity: 0.75
    });

    $('#lineChart').draggable
    ({
        containment: $("#myContainer"),
        cursor: "hand", 
        opacity: 0.75
    });
});


window.onunload = function () {

    //get the coordinates of all divs
}
```

Any help in achieving this would be awesome!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a break and then revisiting this question I was able to achieve the desired effect and wanted to share in hopes of helping someone else in a future situation.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#pieChart").parent().css({ position: "relative" });
    $("#lineChart").parent().css({ position: "relative" });

    $("#pieChart").css({ top: localStorage["pieTop"], left: localStorage["pieLeft"], position:"absolute" });
    $("#lineChart").css({ top: localStorage["lineTop"], left: localStorage["lineLeft"], position:"absolute" });

    $("#pieChart").draggable
    ({
        containment: $("#myContainer"),
        cursor: "hand",
        opacity: 0.75,
    });

    $("#lineChart").draggable
    ({
        containment: $("#myContainer"),
        cursor: "hand", 
        opacity: 0.75
    });
});


$("#pieChart").draggable(
    {
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(event);

            localStorage["pieTop"] = ($('#pieChart').position().top); //offset top
            localStorage["pieLeft"] = ($('#pieChart').position().left); //offset left
        }
    });

$("#lineChart").draggable(
    {
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(event);

            localStorage["lineTop"] = ($('#lineChart').position().top); //offset top
            localStorage["lineLeft"] = ($('#lineChart').position().left); //offset left
        }
    });
```

The above code retrieves the 'top' and 'left' offsets of the divs and places them in local storage. Upon reloading/refreshing the page the divs are positioned according to the previously stored offsets. This is achieved by making the parent page 'relative' and the divs 'absolute' as well as recording the offsets every time the draggable event stopped.

Comment: Hi MattParra: Can you create a simple fiddle to explain how it works? WIll be really fruitful

Comment: I have never created a fiddle but I will definitely oblige the request

Comment: Thanks a lot and appreciate that MattParra